# Load image from drawable folder to webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I've searched but all I can find was making it into a website with the content as the image.
Isn't there any direct way to load an image from the drawable folder in to a webview?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this answer this may help you to solve it..
[Android add image to webview from a drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable)

Comment: You can't load image from drawables however why not you try loading from assets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Android display /res/viewable in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this link : [Android add image to webview from a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable)

You can only do such a thing if our image is inside your /assets folder. Also, you must load your html with a baseUrl that's inside your assets folder.

You can use WebView.loadUrl() or WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL():

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

or

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "", "text/html", "utf-8", null);

(file.jpg should be inside your assets folder)

**Too , see this link:**

[how to load a picture from my resource in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364197/how-to-load-a-picture-from-my-resource-in-webview)

[Android: how to retrieve an image from res/drawable and put it into WebView.loadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373350/android-how-to-retrieve-an-image-from-res-drawable-and-put-it-into-webview-load)

Comment: how about "file:///android_res/drawable/example.png"?

Comment: i think that not load directly "from android_res/drawable" - u should load from "android_asset" folder - just try it!

Answer (score 2):

I have found this answer from other post and it works for me by which we can load resource from drawable also.

```
web_object.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src='test.jpg' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: is this under the same folder?
i mean the image and also the file html?