# Webview in android does not load image from res/drawable

Tags: java, android, webview

This is my code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/sale_screen_20170912.jpg");
        }
    });
```

I want to load an image from drawable resource when receiving an error from webview. But this is what I got when try to load this image from drawable folder.

[image]

API level of the project is 17.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364197/how-to-load-a-picture-from-my-resource-in-webview check this out

Comment: With Asset directory, it works. But what I try is the image from drawable

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src='sale_screen_20170912.jpg' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```